# not able to get mutable reference to the underlying OnceLock data

Tags: rust, lazy-initialization

I'm trying to get a mutable reference to the underlying data of `OnceLock` using `get_mut()` method, but getting error

```
mod OL {
    use std::sync::OnceLock;
    
    static CELL: OnceLock<i32> = OnceLock::new();
    
    pub fn set_cell_val(val: i32) {
        CELL.set(val);
    }
    
    pub fn get_mut_ref() -> &'static mut i32 {
        CELL.get_mut().unwrap()
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Error

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable static item `CELL` as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:11:9
   |
11 |         CELL.get_mut().unwrap()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0596`.
```

Comment: This is the documented behavior of `OnceCell`, which is the non-thread-safe equivalent of `OnceLock`. See [the doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.OnceCell.html), which also explains the alternatives. In your case, it seems that you need the sync-equivalent of `RefCell`, which is a `Mutex`. Beware, however, that you won't be able to get a `&'static mut i32` out of it safely, as calling twice your safe function would be UB.

Comment: I think the doc is missing the explanation of what is really for a OnceCell. From the look at it, it's like a Arc but with some perk. And get_mut is a very nich usecase of OnceCell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OnceLock` is a cell that is assigned *once*. By definition, after being assigned it can no longer change.

`get_mut()` does exist, but it serves niche use cases and definitely not yours. `OnceLock` is just not for you.

What you want is a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html), or a [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html). They can be changed multiple times:

```rust
use std::sync::{Mutex, MutexGuard};

static VALUE: Mutex<i32> = Mutex::new(0);

pub fn set_value(val: i32) {
    *value.lock().unwrap() = val;
}

// This is not a mutable reference, but it acts like one (e.g. it can be assigned into).
pub fn get_mut_ref() -> MutexGuard<'static, i32> {
    VALUE.lock().unwrap()
}
```

If you want a changing value that is also lazily-initialized, you can use `OnceLock<Mutex>`.